# C# datagrid not populating and no error

Tags: c#, datagridview, visual-studio-2015, sqlconnection, sqlcommand

My first problem is that i have a method **private void FillGeneralLedger()**, i put the method in a button on click event to  fill a datagridview **dgvGeneralLedger** my problem is when i run i am not getting an error and the dgv is remaining empty.

My Second problem is i would like to use the same connection but have 5 commands **all the same just different account numbers** eg in the example below the account below is '8200030' i would like to do the same for '8200031','8200032'

```
private void FillGeneralLedger()
    {
        SqlConnection conn = new SqlConnection(sConnectionString);
        try
        {
            DataSet dataset = new DataSet();
            SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("Select Ddate as Date" +
                                                 ", etype" +
                                                 ", Refrence" +
                                                 ", linkacc as ContraAcc" +
                                                 ", Description" +
                                                 ", sum(case when amount > 0 then amount else 0 end) as Debits" +
                                                 ", sum(case when amount < 0 then amount else 0 end) as Credits" +
                                                 ", sum(amount) as Cumulative" +

                                                   " FROM  dbo.vw_LedgerTransactions " +
                                                   " WHERE accnumber = '8200030'" +
                                                   " AND DDate BETWEEN '2016-04-01 00:00:00' AND '2016-04-30 00:00:00'" +
                                                   " AND DataSource = 'PAS11CEDCRE17'" +
                                                   " group by Ddate, etype, Refrence, linkacc, Description, Amount", conn);
            SqlDataAdapter adapter = new SqlDataAdapter(command);
            conn.Open();
            command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            adapter.Fill(dataset);
            if (dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {
                lstGeneralLedger = new List<ReportDataClasses.GeneralLedger>();
                foreach (DataRow row in dataset.Tables[0].Rows)
                {
                    ReportDataClasses.GeneralLedger newGeneralLedger = new ReportDataClasses.GeneralLedger();
                    newGeneralLedger.Ddate = row[0].ToString();
                    newGeneralLedger.etype = row[1].ToString();
                    newGeneralLedger.refrence = row[2].ToString();
                    newGeneralLedger.linkacc = row[3].ToString();
                    newGeneralLedger.Description = row[4].ToString();
                    newGeneralLedger.debit = decimal.Parse(row[5].ToString());
                    newGeneralLedger.credit = decimal.Parse(row[6].ToString());
                    newGeneralLedger.cumulative = decimal.Parse(row[7].ToString());

                    lstGeneralLedger.Add(newGeneralLedger);
                }
                dgvGeneralLedger.DataSource = dataset;
                dgvGeneralLedger.Columns[0].Visible = false;
                pdfCreator.AddGeneralLedgerPage(lstGeneralLedger, 1);
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Application Error. err:" + ex.ToString());
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
        }






    }
```

Comment: Does the code get past `dataset.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0`? Else that means you don't get any result from your SQL command.

Comment: You need to separate your data access (db query) from your presentation (data grid view).  They should not be in the same class, let alone the same method.

Comment: You're executing a NON query, so its not giving you back data, at the same time, you could probably omit the whole command.executenonquery as the commands assigned to the adapater, and just by filling it, it should run it.. but you maybe confusing it.

Comment: PS it make not like things like "as Date" ..  so it maybe trying to give you silent errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why do you use a `DataSet` when you only need a single `DataTable`, this doesn't make any sense. Just use one DataTable:

```
DataTable dataTableSource = new DataTable();
adapter.Fill(dataTableSource);

// .. cotinue your code


dgvGeneralLedger.DataSource = dataTableSource;
```

### Account Number issue:

You can use `SqlParameter` instead of hard-coding the value. Like this:

```
command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@acc", "8200030");
dataTableSource.Load(command.ExecuteReader())
// .. store results ..

// second account
command.Parameters["@acc"].Value = "8200031";
dataTableSource.Load(command.ExecuteReader())

// continue with the rest
```

But you need to change your query to be like this:

```
"... WHERE accnumber = @acc ...."
```

Comment: Hello i got it to work, but i have a second method with the same problem. Im lost confused tried differnt things